# How to get a list of resources linked to a resource in Jena?

Tags: rdf, jena

I created a Model using the Jena APIs:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();

    Resource alice = ResourceFactory.createResource("http://example.org/alice");

    Resource bob = ResourceFactory.createResource("http://example.org/bob");

    Resource charlie = ResourceFactory.createResource("http://example.org/charlie");

    model.add (alice, RDF.type, FOAF.Person);
    model.add (alice, FOAF.name, "Alice");
    model.add (alice, FOAF.mbox, ResourceFactory.createResource("mailto:alice@example.org"));
    model.add (alice, FOAF.knows, bob);
    model.add (alice, FOAF.knows, charlie);

    model.write(System.out, "RDF/XML-ABBREV");
}
```

The output from this program is:

```
<rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
         xmlns:j.0="xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/">
    <j.0:Person rdf:about="example.org/alice">
        <j.0:knows rdf:resource="example.org/charlie"/>
        <j.0:knows rdf:resource="example.org/bob"/>
        <j.0:mbox rdf:resource="mailto:alice@example.org"/>
        <j.0:name>Alice</j.0:name>
    </j.0:Person>
</rdf:RDF>
```

Now how to get a list of resources linked to a certain resource?

For example: Alice knows Bob and Charlie. Alice, Bob and Charlie are resources, Resource Alice knows the other two resources. Now how to get the names [Bob, Charlie]?

Comment: The OUTPUT is: 

<rdf:RDF
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:j.0="http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/">
  <j.0:Person rdf:about="http://example.org/alice">
    <j.0:knows rdf:resource="http://example.org/charlie"/>
    <j.0:knows rdf:resource="http://example.org/bob"/>
    <j.0:mbox rdf:resource="mailto:alice@example.org"/>
    <j.0:name>Alice</j.0:name>
  </j.0:Person>
</rdf:RDF>

Comment: Please include the output in the question instead of referring to a comment.

Answer (score 3):

Jena's Java API documentation shows [there is a method](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/rdf/model/Model.html#listObjectsOfProperty%28com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Resource,%20com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Property%29) just for that:

```
NodeIterator listObjectsOfProperty(Resource s, Property p)
```

This should work in your example:

```
NodeIterator friends = model.listObjectsOfProperty(alice, FOAF.knows);
```

You can then iterate over `friends` to do something with each friend (or acquaintance).