# How to list the objects of rdf statements?

Tags: rdf, jena, ontology

I would like to select a list of the resources related to a given subject resource, via any RDF predicate.

For example, if the resources in my model are `ex:alice`, `ex:bob`, `ex:peter` and `ex:Ben`, and my model contains:

```
ex:alice ex:meet ex:bob.  
ex:alice foaf:knows ex:Peter.  
ex:alice ex:talk :ben.
```

How would I write a method to return list of resources, which are the objects of any triple given a particular resource as the subject? For example, if I give:

```
resourcesRelatedToResource( alice );
```

I expect a list containing Bob, Peter, and Ben.

Comment: Could you perhaps first get back to similar questions you asked? Especially http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15557778/how-to-get-a-list-of-resources-linked-to-a-resource-in-jena is very similar (and I provided an answer).

Comment: Ya but as I mentioned above only by using resourceName the list of objects has to return... not by resource and property.

Comment: It looks like you tried something in another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15935783/return-resource-names-in-object-related-to-resource-subject-using-jena-apis, but there was a comment that asked for more details. Please answer that first, instead of asking new questions.

Comment: I could just about work out what the OP wanted, given the example, so I edited the question to say what I *think* he/she was asking, and then provided my answer!

Answer (score 2):

Using the Jena API, if you call `listStatements` with a null argument for the subject, object or predicate that will act as a wild-card. So you want to just pass the subject Alice, and collect the objects of the matching triples if they are objects. Jena has a short-cut for that: given a resource `r`, the call:

```java
r.listProperties()
```

is equivalent to:

```java
r.getModel().listStatements( r, null, (RDFNode) null )
```

So:

```java
public void test() {
    Model m = /*... your model here ...*/;

    // get a reference to the Alice resource
    Resource alice = m.getResource( NS + "alice" );

    Set<Resource> result = resourcesRelatedToResource( alice );
}

/** Return a set of the resources related to the given input 
  * resource via any predicate */
protected Set<Resource> resourcesRelatedToResource( Resource r ) {
    // we don't care about duplicates, so use a Set
    Set<Resource> objs = new HashSet<Resource>();

    // iterate over the triples with alice as subject
    for (StmtIterator i = r.listProperties(); i.hasNext(); ) {
        RDFNode obj = i.nextStatement().getObject();

        if (obj.isResource()) {
            objs.add( obj.asResource() );
        }
    }

    return objs;
}
```