# List object resources from a instance in Jena

Tags: list, rdf, jena, ontology

How can I list all Object Resources associated to a instance of Resource in Jena?

For example: **Micheal** has an Object Resource called "**Ben**" which is a instance of a Resource **Person**

Comment: Very similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15557778/how-to-get-a-list-of-resources-linked-to-a-resource-in-jena

Comment: Rolled back to previous revision because without the example, the accepted answer makes little sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does an **object resource** reference to? Does the **Person** matters?

If you mean the objects that **Micheal** has object relation with, then you retrieve them by **ListProperties** of the resource, and thus get the objects of these properties.

Answer (score 0):

See the online Apache Jena javadoc:

http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/

Comment: I can see how these questions influence one's mood, but this is not really an answer :)